# iOS: How to terminate extension process from host app?

Tags: ios, process, ios-extensions

Everytime the host app changes the settings, the extension don't update its variables because of cache.

So, i want to terminate extension process from its host app or somehow to communicate with the extension to change its variables.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to terminate the extension from the host app. It is better to design the extension to observe data changes from the host app and reload itself in a timely manner.

For a tutorial on how to reload data in the extension see: http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/

Comment: This way doesn't work with keyboard extension. Because it has separate process